# Facebook API return empty set when going live

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to develop a Facebook App that shows the feed of a Group inside a website.

I had my App reviewed and my permission are:

- email
- groups_access_member_info
- default

My features are:

- Group API

I use my personal Facebook account to login the App and get an Access Token.

This is the code for the login (PHP SDK)

```
  $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v5.0',
  ]);

  $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

  $permissions = ['email','groups_access_member_info'];
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://mywebsite.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);
```

I have 2 problems:

1. After around 15 calls I got an error saying that I reached the limit and I need to wait an hour.
2. If I put the App in Live mode I got an empty set as result.

Below the code for the call:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v5.0',
]);

$fields = array('id', 'name', 'full_picture', 'message', 'permalink_url', 'type', 
'created_time', 'description', 'is_published', 'attachments{media}');

$response = $fb->get('/[GROUP_ID]/feed?fields='.implode(',',$fields), FACEBOOK_TOKEN);

$fb_decodedbody = $response->getDecodedBody();
```

Comment: Did you install the app in the group?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/group/feed#readperms